# jquery remove() equivalent in pure js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I try to remove jquery code and convert it to pure js

```
//old code in jquery
const item = $('[type=item]')
item.text() === '' && $(item).remove()

//new code without jquery
const item = document.querySelector('[type="item"]')
item.innerText === '' && item.parentNode.removeChild(item) // this is problem
```

But I got different behavior using the second block of code, I guess I'm using removeChild wrongly.

Comment: Perhaps you can try `item.parentElement.removeChild`?

Comment: Can you describe the different behaviors you observed  between the two approaches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that `jQuery` removes *all* items which match selector and pure JS (in your version) removes *the first found* node. To remove *all* you can do something like this.

```
const item = document.querySelectorAll('[type=item]');
for(let i=0,it;it=item[i];++i){
    it.innerText === '' && it.parentNode.removeChild(it);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using modern javascript, this should work:

*Look closely - this is not jQuery*

```
//const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document); //<== not needed in _this_ example
const $$ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);
$$('[type=item]').forEach( itm => itm.parentNode.removeChild(itm) );
```

Put the $ and $$ lines at the top of your javascript project, and it should save you some typing - and confuse the jQuery-ites.

References:

https://plainjs.com/javascript/selecting/select-dom-elements-by-css-selector-4/

Answer (score 0):

```
function remove(element) {
element.parentNode.removeChild(element); 
}
```

and use it as

```
<div>
<a href="#" onClick="remove(this.parentNode)">...</a>
</div>
```